# How to make an existing SQL Server database Unicode compatible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. Currently I'm trying to insert Chinese characters into the database, but they are showing up as question marks instead of Chinese characters.

How can I perform this? Is there any solution in database level?

Answer (score 0):

Make Column datatype as `NVARCHAR` with any of the size. And while inserting the data prefix it with `N`. Then it will save and display in Chinese.

Like

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(NAME NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT N'事'
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

And the result will be `事`

**Edit :** From Comments

Yes, you can do it by changing default database collation. But changing the default collation will apply to only the new object created. If you need to Old objects to change Here is a way

[Changing Database Collation](http://samsudeenb.blogspot.in/2007/01/changing-database-collation.html)

Comment: any other db level solutions for this problem? My db has more than 300 tables. changing each columns to NVARCHAR is a time consuming process.

Comment: I have updated answer with reference link..which is worked great for others.